# How to center this logo on a Shopify theme?

Tags: css, sass, shopify, liquid

Working on this site at the moment (https://www.wilsonluxe.com/) - I wanted to put the logo in the middle with the navigation on the left, and potentially the search bar on the right if possible?

I wanted the navigation to be similar to this: https://dealsweel.com/

Any help would be appreciated

I've tried using the Shopify theme liquid but its organised a little differently than vanilla CSS, which is what I'm used to!

Comment: Show us the code u have achieve so far so we can help you better.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `display: flex;`
Try this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px){
    .site-header .grid, .site-header .grid--rev, .site-header .grid--full {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .site-header .grid>.grid__item, .site-header .grid--rev>.grid__item, .site-header .grid--full>.grid__item {
        /* float: none; */
        /* display: table-cell; */
        /* vertical-align: middle; */
        width: 60%;
    }
}

.grid__item.post-large--one-third.post-large--display-table-cell { order: 2; }

.grid__item.post-large--two-thirds.post-large--display-table-cell.medium-down--hide {
    width: 40%;
    display: flex;
    order: 1;
}
```

This is the **result**:
[image]

Comment: hey man, this worked perfectly! Is there any way to center the logo on mobile?

Comment: @AaronMTX I checked the website and it's already centered in mobile viewports

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@media (min-width:992px){ 
    .site-header .grid--full {
        border-bottom: 0;
        width: 66.66%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .site-header .grid--full > .grid__item.post-large--one-third {
        order: 2;
        width: 35%;
    }
    .site-header .grid--full > .grid__item.post-large--two-third {
        width: 65%;
    }
    .header-bar .post-large--display-table {
        position: relative;
    }
    .header-bar .post-large--display-table .header-bar__search {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 110px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .header-bar .post-large--display-table .header-bar__search .header-bar__search-input {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
}
```